# Good scalable fault-tolerant in-memory database with LINQ support for .NET

Tags: fault-tolerance, in-memory-database

Are there are good in-memory transactional databases that support LINQ and SQL Server persistance?  I'd like to create a full representation of a large data store in memory and have it commit to a SQL Server Database in a lazy fashion, but still keep some level of fault tolerance by scaling it out horizontally.  I don't want to rely on non-relational datagrams like CouchDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite supports [in-memory databases](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) has [transaction support](http://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html) and has a [Linq provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319210/how-do-you-use-linq-with-sqlite) as well.

As for the SQL Server persistance, I think you would be on your own to code up something for doing lazy transfers to a backing SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server with an ORM tool and possibly a caching solution.