# Building an application that includes a DB, and need recommendations

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

I'm going to build a little system for personal use, and I want it to save data to a database.
The language is going to be C#, and so I'd like to use this opportunity to get my head around LINQ to SQL.
I have some DB experience and I know my SQL, but it was all in school using Access, which is giving me trouble, and so I'd like to use another DB, something that is small in size, easy to install, and should work with LINQ to SQL.
The problem is: I don't know any except Access, and am looking for recommendations.

To sum it up: I need a lightweight, easy to install, linq-to-sql supporting database for a small system on a home computer, any recommendations?

Comment: What is your qustion? I mean, given that you want to use Linq2SQL, your database choice is made: SQL Server (express).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Microsoft SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/express.aspx) - its free and allows up to 4Gb data

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use a LINQ provider, you can use [SQLLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319210/how-do-you-use-linq-with-sqlite) and [many other databases](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/), but the only supported 'out of the box' choice is [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/express.aspx) (and other SQL Server variants).

Answer (score 0):

I like MySQL even with C#