# Does sqlite support linq-to-SQL?

Tags: sqlite

Does sqlite support linq-to-SQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250071/linq-with-sqlite-linqtosql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No database supports LINQ. LINQ is an abstraction layer on top of the database so it depends on the ADO.NET provider. LINQ-to-SQL is also bound to SQL Server.

That being said [this SQLLite provider](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) has support for LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Yes, Linq-to-Entities = Entity Framework. The OP was asking about Linq-to-SQL, though

Comment: I'm aware of that but I have noticed alot of confusion between LINQ-to-SQL and Entity Framework. Entity Framework is designed to work with any Database where as LINQ-to-SQL is not.

Comment: @willbt - thanks - so if I'm working with SQLite and have a driver/binding that lets me do SQL to the database, then I should be able to get EF working to the it too then?  whereas for Linq-to-sql I'd have to look for specific support in the binding/driver? is this correct

Answer (score 1):

There's a third-party library called [LinqConnect](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/) that is aiming at providing Linq-to-SQL support to a variety of database backends - including SQLite.

Comment: I've just noted another at http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/ .  Any idea which one would be best to go with?

Comment: @Greg: no, since I've never had that requirement, I've never tried either of the two (wasn't aware of the dblinq2007). So I can't give any first-hand reports on which one works better, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [IQToolkit](http://iqtoolkit.codeplex.com/), which does nothing other than reimplement all of LINQ-to-SQL in open source. This is great if you want "raw" access to your database. [IQToolkit Contrib](http://iqtoolkitcontrib.codeplex.com/) could be handy too if you go this route.

If you're more of an ORM type, you could look at SubSonic (which is built on IQToolkit).