# Using SQLite like Linq in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

When using Visual Studio we can create a new item of type Linq to SQL classes (.dbml). After that we can drag and drop tables in the design view and manipulate them.

My question is: Can we use SQLite tables in the same way? Can we drag and drop them so VS can create the classes for us? If not is there a tool that can do that?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ with SQLite (linqtosql)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250071/linq-with-sqlite-linqtosql)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: It seems that it is a duplicate because we can use DBLinq to create .dbml files.

Comment: Maybe use Entity Framework?  Its Linq provider is supposed to be pretty solid against SqLite (or vice-versa :) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can generate .dbml files using the DBLinq from the chosen answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250071/linq-with-sqlite-linqtosql).