# Need a lightweight SQL database for C# supporting LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am making a simple project, and it needs to have a SQL database and I thought using the full SQL Server 2012 would be an overkill.

I want simple and lite database supporting SQL and LINQ queries. I am fairly new to doing databases using C# (only DB related work I did before was MySQL using PHP) and the application is pretty small, only 2 tables atmost, so it better be pretty simple and easy to install and run.

Comment: Like [SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250071/linq-with-sqlite-linqtosql) for instance?

Answer (score 4):

You can use SqlServerCompact 4.0 which is a relatively small self contained assembly you can ship with your app. It's a very trimmed down version of SQL Server but it supports most SQL commands and is supported both with LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework.

http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/07/getting-started-with-sql-server-compact.html

There are other choices as well. SqlLite also has Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL providers.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236918/Using-SQLite-embedded-database-with-entity-framewo

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172417.aspx). It's an embedded SQL Server (runs in medium trust, perfect for hosted web apps!) with some limitations regarding functionalities, data types, and database size - it's limited to 4 GB. You can download it here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876

If you need more, [SQL Server 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) will do. That's what I use on my hobby projects. It's limited to 10 GB per database, but is otherwise pretty similar to the full edition, unless you need advanced stuff. You can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062, and compare the edition features here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx.