# How to use sqlite inmemory for testing puprose in linq2sql

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, linq-to-sql

I am currently working on a legacy project that has DB first ORM 
of linq to sql . 
How can i use the same DBML file and just channge it to use sqlite connection instead of the SQL-Server connection that is used in production?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find a Sql Lite Linq-to-Sql provider. This answer points to one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/459256/736079. Should you want a simple database that is supported out-of-the-box for unit testing purposes, then you can also use SQL Server Compact Edition.