# what should be the database for the windows form application?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I am new to programming in windows environment with Visual Studio most of my work is done in web and PHP .I have to build windows application for a store and the store has to add stock/make bills and sort expired products and the stuff related to stuff so what database backend should i prefer?i thought of microsoft sql but i have to install it on clients system or any simple alternative would be more helpful ?

Comment: This is not a good way to ask. Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a similar question here:

[Local file-based SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385699/local-file-based-sql-server)

I had used SQL Server previously, but like you, it had to go onto a client's computer. I'm now using "Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition (CE)" as suggested in the answer, and this works really well as a standalone database solution.

Answer (score 0):

For deployment point of view I suggest you to use MS Access Database. It is most flexible and simple in use also. Check following link for same

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access/

Answer (score 0):

I am using MDB (access database), but for the next project thinking to go for [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Reason is because MDB access via OleDb is not working in 64 bit applications. You have to compile software as 32 bit, then it will work under 64 bit OS. Or other solution is to install something, called ADE, what will add provider, which solve the issue.